# How to transition 2 divs at the same time?

Tags: css, transition

I'm trying to make an animated menu that when I hover over it , the background (or image) reduces and at the same time the text expands.

Thats my style sheet :

```
.menus {
    float: left;
    background-image: url(images/menus_bg.png);
    width: 208px;
    height: 283px;
    }
.menusimg {
    width: 208px;
    height: 283px;
    position: absolute;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(images/menu1.png);
    }
.menusimg:hover {
    background-size: 80% 80%;
    }
.menusimg, .menusimg:hover {
    -webkit-transition: background-size 0.2s ease-in ;
    }
.menustxtbox {
    font-family: MP;
    padding-top: 240px;
    width: 208px;
    height: 283px;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    font-size: large;
    text-shadow: gray 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
    }
.menustxtbox:hover {
    padding-top: 235px;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: #4fa3f9;
    }
.menustxtbox, .menutxtbox:hover {
    -webkit-transition:font-size 0.1s linear;
    -moz-transition:font-size 0.1s linear;
    }
```

and the html :

```
    <div class="menus">
        <div class="menusimg">
        </div>
        <div class="menustxtbox">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas? A simple Java script or anything that will solve this problem? :)
Thank you in advance ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without any code to see that you've done anything or tried anything with javascript, I would suggest this:

Change your CSS to make real sizes of font size first:

```
.menustxtbox {
    font-size:40px;
}
```

then make some jquery

```
$('.menus').hover(function(){
    $('.menusimg').animate({width: "100px"});
    $('.menustxtbox').animate({fontSize: "90px"});
}, function(){
    $('.menusimg').animate({width: "208px"});
    $('.menustxtbox').animate({fontSize: "40px"});
});
```

Then delete your `:hover` css styles

And if you want to use hover, I would suggest looking into [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html)

**UPDATE** for a comment below

To do this for each separate menu item, you will have to name things a certain way.  Here's an example.

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <div class="menuItem" id="menu1">
        <div class="menusimg"></div>
        <div class="menustxtbox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem" id="menu2">
        <div class="menusimg"></div>
        <div class="menustxtbox"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="menuItem" id="menu3">
        <div class="menusimg"></div>
        <div class="menustxtbox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then with jQuery, you will have to use `$(this)` and `.children()`

```
$('.menuItem').hover(function(){
    $(this).children('.menusimg').animate({width: "100px"});
    $(this).children('.menustxtbox').animate({fontSize: "90px"});
}, function(){
    $(this).children('.menusimg').animate({width: "208px"});
    $(this).children('.menustxtbox').animate({fontSize: "40px"});
});
```

When you use `$(this)`, you will do whatever you want to the specific thing you are trying to use.  Then you just go up or down from there using parent or children to do something to either of those.

Comment: =D
Thanks it works :)
I just need to ajust some details...
THANKS @_@

Comment: You're welcome!  If you wouldn't mind hitting the upvote button and accept the answer, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: 1 - How can i use only onde of this code to more than one separated menus ? or I have to copy to every single one ?
2 - How can I keep the image on the center with this ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to accomodate for your first question.  The second question has to do with your CSS.  You will have to set up a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.net) with your code for me/us to understand best to set up your image being centered.

Comment: I solved the image position problem with jquery margin thanks for everything :)
Now i have some problems but is out of all of this @_@ is another part of the site. where can i contact you ?

Comment: I'm glad you got it!  Take a look at my profile, my email should be available on there.

Answer (score 1):

I second what ntgCleaner said.

In addition you can use:

```
$('.menus').hover(function(){
    $('.menusimg').addClass('active');
    $('.menustxtbox').addClass('active');
}, function(){
    $('.menusimg').removeClass('active');
    $('.menustxtbox').removeClass('active');
});
```

And your css would have:

```
.menusimg.active, .menusimg.active{
 -webkit-transition: background-size 0.2s ease-in ;
}
```

etc.